# Can I tell DD-WRT to allow certain devices to connect without encryption?

Tags: printer, wpa, canon-pixma

I've got a Linksys router running DD-WRT and a crazy long passcode.

My Canon printer used to be connected over Wi-Fi before adding the WPA.

Does anyone know an easier way to connect this thing without having to scroll for hours on end trying to get the password entered into the printer? Perhaps a tweak in DD-WRT to allow it to connect without encryption?

Answer (score 0):

If its the same as the pixma we have in the office, you can run the [windows network settings wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878069.aspx), save the key to a thumbdrive, and set up the printer using that. I cannot remember the settings offhand, but i will update when i next go into the office.

Comment: Hmm. I'm on a Mac. I suppose I could try via VMWare with a USB wifi adaptor. But yea, lemme know :-). Not sure how I would activate it on the printer though.

Comment: Its a text file - so you might be able to edit it if you had the file. I'll look at my office printer later, and see if i can get an example text file